# Convert MySQL database from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, migration, innodb, myisam, resource-cleanup

I have to convert Mysql database from MyISAM to InnoDB.

The problem is that existing MyISAM database has a lot of inconsistent data that would make problem in InnoDB. There are invalid foreign key references everywhere, so in the process of switching storage engine I will have to clean up the junk from the database.

Is there some tool that will help me to detect those invalid fk references, since manually checking every relation would be a huge job?

Can someone who already did that share the experience, and what would be the best approach.

Comment: How many tables are involved?  If it's just a few, then you could always just do some creative joins in delete queries.  (Am assuming that you have a large number of tables or you would have already done something like that -- just figured no harm in throwing it out there.)

Comment: Can you tell me how you created FK in MyISAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roland Bouman posted a tool for this a few years ago. I've used it in the past and found it helpful.

Here's a link to it:

http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=11